# CURRENT_DATE in postgresql triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have before insert trigger in postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_requestdate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE

BEGIN

    new.requestdate := now();

    RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER addrequestdate
BEFORE INSERT ON requests FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_requestdate ();
```

But it doesn't work! I have solution that works...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_requestdate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE

BEGIN

    UPDATE requests SET requestdate=now() WHERE id=NEW.id;

    RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER addrequestdate
BEFORE INSERT ON requests FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_requestdate ();
```

I have only one question. Why `new.requestdate := now();` doesn't work?

Comment: What error gives? In my version of PostgreSQL 9.0, the first example works without problem. You can put the table definition, and the SQL command that you run? And your version of PostgreSQL is?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work!". The second trigger can only have an effect if `requests.id` is not unique - on other rows with the same `id`. Is `id` unique? Are there additional other triggers involved?

Answer (score 3):

it working - probably you have some other dependency - it strange, your workable solution cannot to work, because before trigger doesn't see a tuple in table, and if you use after trigger, then you start recursion..

```
postgres=# create table x(a int, b date, c timestamp);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create function fxx()
postgres-# returns trigger as $$
postgres$# begin
postgres$#   new.b := now();
postgres$#   new.c := now();
postgres$#   return new;
postgres$# end;
postgres$# $$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# create trigger xxxx before insert on x for each row execute procedure fxx();  
CREATE TRIGGER
postgres=# insert into x(a) values(10);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into x(a) values(209);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from x;
  a  │     b      │             c              
─────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────
  10 │ 2012-01-07 │ 2012-01-07 18:36:57.665283
 209 │ 2012-01-07 │ 2012-01-07 18:37:00.853442
(2 rows)
```

so, you can use CURRENT_DATE instead now(), it is preferable solution.